# Gdalwarp fails to properly reproject to custom projection

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp

I am trying to reproject my tif file to custom EPSG:3857 projection.
Input file picture + gdalinfo:
[image]

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: shd_120arcsec.tif
   shd_120arcsec.tif.aux.xml
Size is 10800, 5100
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
DATUM["WGS_1984",
    SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,85.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.033333333333333,-0.033333333333333)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
    Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  85.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 85d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -85.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 85d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  85.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 85d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -85.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 85d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=10800x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=-7.000 Max=99.000 
  Minimum=-7.000, Maximum=99.000, Mean=76.225, StdDev=4.133
  Metadata:
    COLOR_TABLE_RULES_COUNT=5
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_0=-1.900000e+01 4.600000e+00 255 255 0 0 255 0
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_1=4.600000e+00 2.820000e+01 0 255 0 0 255 255
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_2=2.820000e+01 5.180000e+01 0 255 255 0 0 255
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_3=5.180000e+01 7.540000e+01 0 0 255 255 0 255
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_4=7.540000e+01 9.900000e+01 255 0 255 255 0 0
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=99
    STATISTICS_MEAN=76,225048868313
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-7
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=4,1329152918177
```

I reproject it with this command:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=179.9 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs" -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE input.tif output.tif
```

Result picture + gdalinfo:
[image]

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: shd_120arcsec_3857_180.tif
       shd_120arcsec_3857_180.tif.aux.xml
Size is 11983, 11944
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed ellipse",
    DATUM["unknown",
        SPHEROID["unnamed",6378137,0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",179.9],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-20037505.625028245151043,19971868.880408562719822)
Pixel Size = (3344.079316992716940,-3344.358408907004559)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-20037505.625,19971868.880) (  0d 5'59.91"W, 85d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-20037505.625,-19973147.956) (  0d 5'59.91"W, 85d 0' 3.60"S)
Upper Right (20034596.830,19971868.880) (  0d 7'34.16"W, 85d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (20034596.830,-19973147.956) (  0d 7'34.16"W, 85d 0' 3.60"S)
Center      (   -1454.397,    -639.538) (179d53'12.97"E,  0d 0'20.68"S)
Band 1 Block=11983x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=-9.000 Max=99.000 
  Minimum=-9.000, Maximum=99.000, Mean=75.447, StdDev=9.114
  Metadata:
    COLOR_TABLE_RULES_COUNT=5
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_0=-1.900000e+01 4.600000e+00 255 255 0 0 255 0
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_1=4.600000e+00 2.820000e+01 0 255 0 0 255 255
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_2=2.820000e+01 5.180000e+01 0 255 255 0 0 255
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_3=5.180000e+01 7.540000e+01 0 0 255 255 0 255
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_4=7.540000e+01 9.900000e+01 255 0 255 255 0 0
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=99
    STATISTICS_MEAN=75,447325377618
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-9
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=9,1141517462422
```

Result looks good except the 0 values (black strip) around 180. Since I need especially this data around 180 longitude, result is not ok for me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Things to try:

- pass this option `-wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000`
- convert to 0-360 without warping:
  `gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84" -t_srs WGS84 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 --config CENTER_LONG 0 input.tif output.tif`